# Best Travel Kata C++

Tags: c++, time-limit-exceeded

https://www.codewars.com/kata/best-travel

Briefly, the problem states that we have to create a function `choose_best_sum(int t, int k,std::vector<int> xs)` that will take as parameters t (maximum sum of elements, integer >= 0), k (number of elements to be chosen from the vector, k >= 1) and ls (list of **positive** elements to choose k elements from). The function returns the "best" sum i.e. the biggest possible sum of k elements less than or equal to the given limit t, if that sum exists, or otherwise -1.

For Example:

If `ls` = [50, 55, 57, 58, 60], `t` = 174 and `k` = 3,

Then all the possible choices of `k`(3) elements in `ls` are:

[50,55,57],[50,55,58],[50,55,60],[50,57,58],[50,57,60],[50,58,60],[55,57,58],[55,57,60],[55,58,60],[57,58,60]

The corresponding sums are then: 162, 163, 165, 165, 167, 168, 170, 172, 173, 175.

Out of which, 173 is the largest sum less than `t`(174),so the function `chooseBestSum(int t, int k, std::vector<int>& ls)` returns 173.

From what I understand of the problem, one must basically enumerate and the compare all the possible combinations of k elements from the vector. My solution works, but times out, so it isn't accepted. I've basically tried to create a sliding window that slides through the vector and adds the elements inside the window to i-th and j-th elements and then adds them all to a local sum variable to be compared to the best sum. I know that four for-loops are a performance nightmare for a problem like this. What can I do to optimize it? Or is their an obvious other strategy that I'm missing?

````cpp
class BestTravel
{
public:
    static int chooseBestSum(int t, int k, std::vector<int>& ls);
};

int BestTravel::chooseBestSum(int t, int k, std::vector<int>& ls){
    int best_sum = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<=ls.size()-k;i++){ //selects the first element for each combination
        for(int s=i+1;s<ls.size()-(k-2);s++){ //creates a sliding window(?) for k-2 elements
        int l_sum = ls[i];
          for(int x = s;x<s+(k-2);x++){ // iterates through the window and adds the elements to the local sum (l_sum)
          l_sum+=ls[x];
          }
          for(int j = ls.size()-1;j>=s+(k-2);j--){//adds the remaining elements from the end to the local sum
           l_sum+=ls[j];
           if(l_sum<=t&&l_sum>best_sum){best_sum = l_sum;}
           l_sum-=ls[j];
          }
        }
    }
    return best_sum;
}



```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! would you please include a section in your question that reiterates the problem statement so that users don't have to navigate away from the page in order to figure out what you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Malachi♦ Thank You! I have added the problem statement in the question,

Comment: Can the elements of the vector also be negative? Does the code work? Can you give examples of input and output? Now, there is no function named 'choose_best_sum()'.  You wrapped a class around your code for no reason, remove the class and the habit. Format your code consistently. Don't try to solve timing problems by cramming as much code as possible on one line. That only makes your code unreadable, not fast. Sorry for being harsh, but at that point my review stops. Fix those points first, then your question will start to attract people for a more in-depth review.

Comment: @uli Thank you for the feedback! I have added an example.My function _does_ work, but it is too slow.

Comment: What about all the other problems with your question?